# How do I use Write-Output and Write-Information without duplication

Tags: powershell

I want to output results to screen as well as to information stream without duplicating data. Is there a better way to do that rather then just do the same thing all the time

```
Write-Output "Some data logged"
Write-Information "Some data logged"
```

Comment: Typically, I write a logging function with similar semantics to the Write-* functions.   You can have a function that will take input from the pipeline so you can `$foo | Write-Logger` or `Write-Logger $foo`.  The function can do both of your steps above, or use Tee-Object to write to a file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use write-output to output to the screen, write-information can already do that but you may need to set:

$InformationPreference = 'continue'

In your script.  Use write-output when you want to return output to the pipeline. Write-information is a way to show a message in the console without affecting the pipeline.

Comment: Any idea how to output -Verbose output also to Information output?

Comment: To output -verbose information use write-verbose instead.

Comment: How do I capture -verbose into variable then? If I have function in which I use write-verbose and I'd like to call that function and capture Verbose output in variable, how do I do that?

Comment: `$o = (Write-Verbose -Verbose "Hello") 4>&1;$o`   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/